# webBrowser elements not populating in revised code

Tags: c#

I am rewriting a large portion of my program and have run into something that makes no since to me at all.

The first block of code works perfectly.  The web page opens in the webBrowser control.  The username field populates, as well as the password field.  And the button clicks without any issue.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TimeClockEntry2
{
    public partial class PNow : Form
    {
        int linkcount = 0;
        string userName;
        string passWord;

        public PNow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
//            ControlBox = false;  // This line hides the Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://ew23.ultipro.com/login.aspx");
        }

        private void PNow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            userName = Properties.Settings.Default.userName;
            passWord = Properties.Settings.Default.passWord;
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            linkcount++;

            if (linkcount == 1)
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("Value", userName);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_Password").SetAttribute("value", passWord);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The second block of code opens the web page and then stops.  Nothing else happens.

Any ideas would be awesome, thank you.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TimeClockEntry3
{
    public partial class PNow : Form
    {
        int linkcount = 0;
        string userName;
        string passWord;

        public PNow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
//            ControlBox = false;  // This line hides the Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://ew23.ultipro.com/login.aspx");
        }

        private void PNow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            userName = Properties.Settings.Default.USERNAME;
            passWord = Properties.Settings.Default.PASSWORD;

            //MessageBox.Show(userName);
            //MessageBox.Show(passWord);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            linkcount++;

            if (linkcount == 1)
            {
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("Value", userName);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_Password").SetAttribute("value", passWord);
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some narrative to explain the intent of the code and how the first sample differs from the second? That might make it a little easier to follow.

Comment: The intent of the code is to open a web page and log into it.  I have edited the code to remove irrelevant code to the issue.

Comment: The intent of the code is to open a web page and log into it.  I have edited the code to remove irrelevant code to the issue.  The two blocks of code are identicle with the exception of a variable name being changed.  I have confirmed that the variable name change is not the issue.  The second block of code opens the web page in the webBrowser control but stops at that point.  It does not populate the the fields or click on the button.  The exact same code works fine in the first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...

I needed to associate the the DocumentCompleted event in the form properties.
Thank you.